# CSS no background image, any ideas?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my background image to show at the top center of the page. The image works fine if I do:

```
<style>
  body {
   background: #FFF url('img/top_logo_blank_small.png') no-repeat fixed;
  }
</style>
```

I can't seem to work out where I've gone wrong. There must be something I've managed to mess up, I just can't see it. Here is the CSS:

```
body {
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #EEE url('img/top_logo_blank_small.png') no-repeat fixed;
color: #fff;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

a {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* Typography */

.header h1 {
position: absolute;
width:100%;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -20px;
text-align: center;
letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.header h1 em {
font-size: 1.200em;
font-style: normal;
}

h1 {
font-size: 2.2em;
color: #fff;
}

.content h2 {
font-size: 1.75em;
color: #fff;
letter-spacing: 4px;
text-align: center;
}

.content h2 em {
font-size: 1.2em;
font-style: normal;
}

.content h3 {
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.0em;
font-weight: normal;
color: #ede0ed;
letter-spacing: 1px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.content h4 {
margin-top: 0;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-weight: normal;
color: #ede0ed;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#banner p {
text-align: center;
}

/* Navigation */

#nav {
margin: 4px 4px 40px;
}

#nav ul {
padding: 0;
margin: auto;
list-style: none;
}

#nav ul li {
width: 50%;
color: #BBB;
float: left;
font-family: 'Cabin Sketch';
font-size: 1.75em;
text-align: center;
background: url(img/scribble_dark.png);
}

#nav ul li a {
display: block;
/*padding: 5px 20px;*/
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
background: #e0d0e0;
}

/* Content */

.container{
max-width: 720px;
margin: 50px auto 0;
background: #FFF url('img/top_logo_blank_small.png') no-repeat fixed 0 0;
}

.header {
position: relative;
background-color: #b88fb8;
border-top: 5px solid #ede0ed;
height: 75px;
}

.content {
background-color: #000;
padding: 15px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div#about {
padding:25px;
min-height: 255px;
}

img#portrait {
float: left;
margin-right: 25px;
width: 256px;
height: 256px;
}

div#footer {
width: 100%;
max-width: 720px;
margin: auto;
color: black;
text-align: right;
padding: 0 10px;
font-size: 0.850em;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

.container { 
    width: 90%;
    max-width: none;
}

div#footer {
    width: 90%;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you actually want it to be fixed or just top center? If it's just "top center" then remove fixed and simply put "center 0" insted of "fixed top". Also check the path to your image is correct.

Comment: Yeah the aim is to keep the image fixed. I needed to go up one directory which apparently I missed. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your path for example:

```
background: #EEE url('../img/top_logo_blank_small.png') no-repeat fixed top;
```

Because you are in a subfolder, you have to go up of a level I think

Comment: Actually, the 'img' folder is in the same directory as the html document. As I say, it works if I use `<style>` in the html doc with that same path.

Comment: you are welcome, if you have solved the problem accept the answer to help other people if they have a similar problem

Comment: No wait, I edited the comment, but you were right. Thee CSS file is in a seperate folder... I maybe need to take a break. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your css file is in a different folder and therefore needs another path to the image file.

The common way is to put css in a separate `css/*` folder, so the path should be:

```
url('../img/top_logo_blank_small.png')
```

Comment: You're right buddy, I'm just loosing concentration apparently. Alessandro did answer first which is why I've made his the top answer, but I'll still upvote.

Comment: @FiferSheep actually, my answer was one minute earlier but never mind that;) Glad we could help:-D

Answer (score 1):

This CSS seems to work fine, are you certain that the image exists?

http://jsfiddle.net/ghsNR/

I've just tried it here and it works fine with an image from http://placehold.it/

```
body {
font-family: 'Quattrocento Sans', helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #EEE url('http://placehold.it/500x500') no-repeat fixed top;
color: white;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```

The most likely cause after observing this is that your CSS isn't actually locating your image correctly. I suggest using tools like the Chrome dev tools, or Firebug to inspect the absolute path that the browser is trying to use to load the image and moving forward from there.

Comment: so, placehold is back up. nice +1 for showing how rapid prototyping can be done.

Comment: I needed to move up one directory first which was my problem, but thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Is the css in the same folder as the page? If you have a different folders, you need to change the URL accordingly.

Maybe change the URL to

```
'../img/top_logo_blank_small.png'
```

Comment: Yeah, apparently I missed this one. Thanks for the help, it's much appreciated!